# Is it safe to call other virtual methods in virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, destructor

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() { this->f(); }

    virtual void f() {};
};

struct B : A
{
    int* p;

    B() : p(new int) {}

    ~B()
    {
        delete p;
        p = 0;
    }

    void f() override { *p = 0; }
};

int main()
{
    delete new B; // Is it safe?
}
```

Is it safe to call other virtual methods in virtual destructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe if you know the rules, and the rules say that within a destructor, the dynamic type of the object is the class whose destructor is executing.

While `B::~B()` is executing, the type of the object is `B` (and if you call `f()` then, you'll get dispatched to `B::f()`

While `A::~A()` is executing, the type of the object is `A`, and if you call `f()` then, you get undefined behavior per §10.4[class.abstract]/6

> Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making a virtual call to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created (or destroyed) from such a constructor (or destructor) is **undefined**

Or, as clang++ reports it,

```
test.cc:5:20: warning: call to pure virtual member function 'f'; overrides of 'f' in subclasses are not available in the destructor of 'A'
    virtual ~A() { this->f(); }
                   ^
test.cc:7:5: note: 'f' declared here
    virtual void f() = 0;
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

EDIT: OP edited pure virtual out.. so, then, while `A::~A()` is executing, virtual call to `f()` gets dispatched to `A::f()`

Comment: It's not undefined if a body has been provided for the pure virtual.

Comment: I asked a question to be sure.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456450/is-it-safe-to-call-a-pure-virtual-function-in-an-abstract-constructor-destructor

Answer (score 1):

Note: the OP edited the code to remove the pure virtual part.

With what you have posted, no it is not safe. When you call a virtual function in a constructor or destructor of a class in an inheritance hierarchy, it does not call the most derived function as usual, but calls the function defined within the current class.

In this case, ~A calls A::f() which has no function body, so this is an error. If you provided a body for A::f() (you can do this with pure virtuals, just outside the class definition), then it would be "safe", although whether it does what you want is another matter.